# spectral structure of sinusoidal model

Tags: matlab, math, fft, spectral-density

let us consider following code

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 %plot(x);
end
```

as i know  peaks in   Fourier domain represent    at this frequency,which are present in signal,for example let us take  plot of Fourier transform of this signal
let us run this signal

```
y=generate1(3,500,1);
```

and  plot

```
plot(abs(fft(y)))
```

[image]

but clearly it does not shows me  peaks at frequency  given in signal,what is problem?please help me,generally  it is stationary signal,that why  this  graph should show me exact  picture but it does not do,why?

EDITED :

y1=generate1(3,500,0);
[image]

Comment: Could you plot y=generate1(3,500,0); so as to compare?

Comment: yes sure ,i will do it

Comment: @Oxinabox  i have done it

Comment: Hmm that is kinda odd, let me check that out with matlab

Comment: sorry?i did not understand

Comment: what is reason i did not understand

Comment: I am not quiet sure, i think you might not be using Plot right, i think you need a X axis

Comment: X axis how? like axis([0 200  0 300]) or  how?

Comment: like plot(abs(fft(y, xf),xf) or something like that is , trying to work this out. (It has been a while since i have done this)

Comment: i have post it  there http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13527/spectral-structure-of-sinusoidal-model but no result

Comment: Please do not cross post between stack exchange websites

Comment: ok,so in your mind what should be problem there?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry i couldn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function [ x, fs ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 %plot(x);
 fs = 1/(t(2)-t(1));
end
```

and see

```
absfft = abs(fft(y));
plot(fs/2*linspace(0,1,length(absfft)/2+1),2*absfft(1:end/2+1))
```

or

```
plot(linspace(-fs/2,fs/2,length(absfft)),fftshift(absfft))
```

the x-axis in your plot is from 0 to fs/2 and then from -fs/2 to 0

Comment: fs is sampling frequency, fs must be at least to times the highest frequency present in your signal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)